# How do I create a reference to a public class in wpf resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in this most trivial example. How do I create a resource that references a public class in the local namespace of my project?

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Foo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:Bar x:Key="MyBar" /><!-- problem here -->
        </Grid.Resources>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {

    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

When I do this, I get the error `The name "Bar" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Foo".`

This question is almost identical to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322591/wpf-cant-instantiate-class-in-window-resources) but my class is already public.

Comment: Does it work when you move your `Bar`-class to a seperate file?

Comment: Try this: Remove the resource, build the project, add the resource again. XAML often needs the classes to exist in the assembly before you can use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build the project, it should work, it's correct.

Comment: If you build project, you get same error. but as @Manfred said if you remove, build, and add problem solved(-1 is not mine)

Comment: I also tried, and didnt work. May be it depends on project

Comment: Thank you, this turned out to be the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try to to inherit your class from UserControl

```
public class Bar : UserControl
{

}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379.aspx